# DOCTYPE messes up formatting

Tags: html, css, format

I know many people have similar problems when switching to the `<!DOCTPYE html>` line, however,  I've tried all the methods and even the classic

`html{height: 100%;}
 body {min-height: 100%;}`

method, along with others, but sadly, I cannot figure out how to insert this into my code. Every time I add the `DOCTYPE`, my background image disappears, I tried the method for background images, as well.

Here's my code- http://pastebin.com/554Mctvx
I want there to still be a center div.
I hope you guys can help :D

**~Wumbo**

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `<!DOCTYPE html>`at the top of your `html` file according to the **W3C** standardization.

1. Create separate CSS file as `mystyle.css` and put all your **css** code there.
2. Make a link of your css file like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">`

```css
::-moz-selection {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #00ffaa;
}

::selection {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #00ffaa;
}

a:link {
    color: #00ffaa;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: #00d486;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: #57ffd5;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: #00ffaa;
}
#center{
width:80%;
height:125%;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
background-color:2d2d2d;
}
```

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://i.imgur.com/Bj3KBRt.png" type="image/x-icon" />
<title>Welcome to Wumbo's Site</title>

<body background="http://i.imgur.com/hySVC7M.png">
<div id="center">
<center>
<h1><font face="trebuchet MS" color="dbdbdb">This Site is Under Construction!</h1>
<p>In a few months, when I am finished, I will unveil this site! In the meantime,
also for updates, follow me on twitter.
<br>
I also have a Youtube channel where I upload stupid crap!</p>
<br>
<h1>MY SOCIAL NETWORKZ</h1>
<a href="https://twitter.com/BullCloaker">Twitter</a>
<br>
<a href="https://youtube.com/user/calluvdutyplayr9"> My Youtube Channel</a>
<p> I'm not sure what I'm going to do with this site,
<br>
But it will most likely be a portfolio, where I share all the drawings,
<br>
animations and other such things I've made.
<br>
Seeya!
<br>
<font face="trebuchet MS" color="#00ffaa"> ~Wumbo ( &#865;&#176; &#860;&#662; &#865;&#176;)</font>
</font>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<font face="Arial" color="#00ffaa" size="1">You are currently using the Dark Site Skin.<a href="file:///C:/Users/jeanpaul/Desktop/Websites/SiteLight.html">Click Here to use the Light Site Skin</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<a href="file:///C:/Users/jeanpaul/Desktop/Websites/AboutPageDark.html">About</a>  &#8226;  <a href="https://google.com">Gallery</a>  &#8226;  <a href="https://google.com">Videos</a>  &#8226;  <a href="file:///C:/Users/jeanpaul/Desktop/websites/SiteDark.html">Main</a>
</center>
</div>
```

** Try to follow some standard tutorial to manage your html, css code. It will not be a mess. Now a days there are lots of html/css project management tools are available to make your code clean and readable.

Comment: Thank you very much! I never would have guessed I needed to seperate the stylesheet :P

Comment: Welcome. Can you please upvote my answer. I don't know why it is down voted ?

Comment: I did, but it doesn't show up, as I'm new, I don't have enough reputation for it to show up, I also had a quick question, how do I make the inner div visible, I cannot see it after the steps.

Comment: No problem. I asked, but you didn't see it, how do I get my inner div to show up in it?

Comment: The center one. I'm not sure if I understand your question but I think the answer you're looking for is the center one :P
[This](http://i.imgur.com/AlkRX2r.jpg)

Comment: Ok, I got it. I think, you need to study thoroughly of the html,css.

`<div id = "center"> <center> </center></div>`

Here you have two html tags `div` and `center`, the `div` tag has an `id` which mapped to your css file `#center` for some styling. Now this `div id` `#center` doesn't have any relation with `<center>` tag. You can modify the `<div id = "d1">` and change into the css file also `#d1` (replace #center). You ll get same result. Actually you are able to see both `div` and `center` tag. The `center` is into `div` tag property.

Comment: I don't what you mean by that, sorry.

Comment: Alright, I fixed it, thanks so much for your help, I'll be sure to include you in the credits page of the site. :D

Comment: 1 more comment needed for an achievement, ignore. :P